# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0)demosaicing.cpp:1721 error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function 'demosaicing'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I'm getting the following OpenCV-Python error while running a face recognition module in Python 3.8.2:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/demosaicing.cpp:1721: error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function 'demosaicing'
```

Could someone explain the cause of this error and the solution to it?

Here is the code:

```py
known_faces=[]
known_names=[]

for name in os.listdir(KNOWN_FACES_DIR):
    for filename in os.listdir(f"{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}"):
        image=face_recognition.load_image_file(f"{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}/{filename}")
        encoding=face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
        known_faces.append(encoding)
        known_names.append(name)

print("processing unknown faces!")
for filename in os.listdir(UNKNOWN_FACES_DIR):
    print(filename)
    image=face_recognition.load_image_file(f"{UNKNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{filename}")
    locations= face_recognition.face_locations(image,model=MODEL)
    encodings=face_recognition.face_encodings(image,locations)
    image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of testing and searching. I think the error is due to incorrect format of the pictures that I uploaded.

I found this definition from wikipedia

A demosaicing (also de-mosaicing, demosaicking or debayering) algorithm is a digital image process used to reconstruct a full color image from the incomplete color samples output from an image sensor overlaid with a color filter array (CFA). It is also known as CFA interpolation or color reconstruction.

I tried changing the code but to no avail. Then after seeing the definition thought it might be incorrect input from the picture. I think it's the type of format of of picture that I found incorrect.